# Solidity assembly: why is the length of _bytes added to _bytes before mload()?

Tags: solidity, evm

For example in BytesLib: https://github.com/GNSPS/solidity-bytes-utils/blob/master/contracts/BytesLib.sol#L348  (Edit: Note that the same pattern is used for lengths: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, and 32)

```
    function toUint96(bytes memory _bytes, uint _start) internal  pure returns (uint96) {
        require(_bytes.length >= (_start + 12));
        uint96 tempUint;

        assembly {
            tempUint := mload(add(add(_bytes, 0xc), _start))
        }

        return tempUint;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, `add(_bytes, 0xc)` adds `12` (`0x0c`) to the address of `_bytes`.

`add(add(_bytes, 0xc), _start)` adds `12` and `_start` to the address of `_bytes`.

`mload(add(add(_bytes, 0xc), _start))` loads onto the stack `32` bytes starting from the address of `_bytes` increased by `12` and `_start`.  In other words, it loads bytes at offsets `(12 + _start) ... (43 + _start)` counting from the address of `_bytes`.

`tempUint := mload(add(add(_bytes, 0xc), _start))` converts just loaded 32-byte value into `uint96`.  This means, that only the last `12` bytes of the laded value are assigned to `tempUint`: the bytes with offsets `(32 + _start) ... (43 + _start)`.

Taking into accounts, that `bytes.length` occupies the first `32` bytes of `_bytes`, and `_bytes` contents starts from offset 32, we conclude, that `tempUint` will receive 12 bytes at offsets `_start ... (11 + _start)` of `_bytes` contents.

Comment: Thanks!  It took your walk through for me to get it.